# Копирование в массив с определенной позиции

Tags: массивы, char, c++

Как можно скопировать часть из массива `char * mem1` в массив `char * mem2` с определенной позиции? Допустим в первом массиве хранится 11223344, а во второй нужно скопировать только 223344. Как это сделать? Я пытался сделать что-то типа: `memove(s, s+1, (sizeof(s)-1));` Но при вводимых данных 1234567890 выводится 2344567890, почему удваивается 4-ка?

Comment: Выложите свой код. Так будет намного легче найти ошибку.

Comment: Самое простое

    strcpy(mem2, mem1 + 2);

если Вам нужно "до конца строки" и mem1,mem2 **разные** массивы.

По поводу второго примера (с удвоение 4-ки) напишите поподробнее код и вводимые Вами денные.

Вообще же - **sizeof(s)** это размер занимаемой массивом памяти, к текущей длине сторки (символы, заканчивающиеся двоичным нулем) прямого отношения не имеет.

Comment: Код такой:
<code>
size = inFile.tellg();
memblock = new char [size];
inFile.seekg (0, ios::beg);
inFile.read (memblock, size);
memmove(memblock, memblock+1, (sizeof(memblock)-1));
outFile.write (memblock, sizeof(memblock));
</code>

Comment: Прошу прощения, не подскажите какие теги для вставки кода?

Comment: Для создания блоков кода или другого форматированного текста, отступите четыре пробела

Comment: Для форматирования кода вставляйте 4 пробела в начале каждой строки. Можете также править свой вопрос, дополнять  его кодом.

Ну, в коде понятная ошибка. Вы пишете 

    sizeof(memblock)

а `memblock` это указатель (4 байта в 32-бит компе). Вот и двигаете 4 символа.

Вы же считали `size` байт (или меньше). Вам надо сдвинуть все на 1 символ к началу? 

Проще всего (но неправильно)

    memmove(memblock, memblock + 1, size - 1); 
    
поскольку Вы не знаете сколько на самом деле прочли. Правильно

    inFile.read(memblock, size); int rlen = inFile.gcount();
    memmove(..., rlen - 1);

(мало ме

Comment: (мало места)

итак, прочли `rlen` байт.

Если надо сдвинуть, то очевидно

     memmove(memblock, memblock + 1, rlen -1);

Дальше вы пишете

     outFile.write (memblock, sizeof(memblock));

вряд ли Вы хотите записать в файл 4 байта. Если надо записать прочитанные данные с удвоеным последним символом, то пишите

    outFile.write (memblock, rlen);

если же хотели записать все без первого байта, то и сдвигать не надо

   inFile.read(memblock, size); int rlen = inFile.gcount();
   outFile.write (memblock + 1, rlen - 1);

наверное все.

Comment: Спасибо за ответы, но у меня маленькое дополнение: что нужно сделать чтобы программа работала с файлами очень большого размера? Ведь тот способ который вы мне подсказали ограничен Int.

Comment: @MartinSeptim, в таком случае опишите свою задачу.

Что Вам точно нужно сделать с файлами размером больше 2GB?

И лучше в новом вопросе (у меня здесь комментарии закончились. Лимит...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    char * mem1 = "11223344";
    char mem2[6];

    copy(mem1 + 2, mem1 + 8, mem2); 
    cout << mem2 << endl;

    return 0;
}
```